# Cannot fetch string with special symbols actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

Hi I am new to actionscript.
I am tring to fetch string from html in flash project using actionscript.

When I pass a normal string it reflects where as string with special symbols does not.
like append:"&m=32&mc=12&csc=t";

Kindly suggest some way to receive it using actionscript.
And is there any restriction on length of string in actionscript that can received using LoaderInfo??

Comment: Try use \ symbol before special symbol for example show("Click \" df");

Comment: Thanks @Anton for reply . I tried like:  https://www.abc.com/t/thome.do?tc=y\&m=   ..... but it is not working.. i hv to do it for special symbol'&' ... actually everything after '&' is not getting fetched.

Comment: Try use special character &amp; instead &. (http://www.utexas.edu/learn/html/spchar.html)

Comment: Thanks @Anton but still it does not takes string after '&' be it '&amp'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to pass part of a url.

One the JS/HTML side, encode it using `encodeURIComponent()` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent), then reverse it on the AS3 side using `decodeURIComponent()` ([http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#decodeURIComponent()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/package.html#decodeURIComponent%28%29))

Alternatively, you can also encode using JSON, or Base64, etc